# How to find inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, inner-products, orthogonality

[image: Question]

I understand that this is via inner products. However, I don't quite understand the relation and how to find $v_2, v_3, v_4$ from the matrix.

For part (b), I hypothesise that if $v_4$ is a zero vector, then it would mean that $v_1, v_2, v_3 and v_4$ are colinear. Is it correct to conclude it this way or am I heading in the wrong direction?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's not colinear. It's clear that "second row" is not a multiple of "first row". Do you know of Gram-Schmidt process? Also, for finding $v_2,v_3,v_4$ you do not use matrix. You just find $v_1=\text{first row}$ and find rest by iterative relation given.

Comment: Your final conclusion is in the right direction, but it's not exactly correct either. It means that $u_1, u_2, u_3$ and $u_4$ lie in the same three-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$, not necessarily on the same line.

Comment: Well, what is stopping you in part (a)? Is it "let $u_i$ be the ith row"? Is it $u_2\cdot v_1$? or dividing that by $v_1\cdot v_1$? or multiplying that by $v_1$? or subtracting that from $u_2$?

Comment: Not collinear, but *linearly dependent*.

To find $v_{2}$, slow down and first find the inner product $u_{2} \cdot v_{1}$.